# MinGW64 cannot compile 32bit code

Tags: c++11, mingw32, mingw-w64

I've downloaded MinGW from this link [x64-4.8.1-posix-sjlj-rev1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/?source=dlp) but when I try to build for x86 target I've lots of linkage errors... seems that only x64 lib are installed...

I've need to build for x86 and x64 platforms on windows... Have I to download both x64 and x86 or are some simpler ways?

**Edit**  I'm using eclipse keplero as IDE
I've tryed to build myself a simple hello world program with `g++ -m32 -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test32.exe` and `g++ -m64 -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test64.exe`. And all is ok... So the problem was with eclipse... After a little a discovered that I need to use MYSY ( set in PATH ) and set -m32 also in the c++ linkage options...

Now all is fine.

I've also tryed to use NetBeans C++ as IDE... seems a gread IDE!!!

Comment: You know all there is to know, now go download the 32-bit version.

Comment: well on linux i have multilib for this and ther's `Multilib toolchains` I thought that it was "automatic"

Comment: Then go look for multilib mingw.

Comment: well i can only choose between win32 and win64

Comment: You're wrong, you can build your own multilib mingw.

Comment: Use MinGW for 32 bit compilation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not `multilib` enabled. That's why you are not able to compile 32-bit(x86) program. You can get `multilib` enabled toolchain from following link:

For 64-bit machine: [64-Bit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/gcc-4.8-release/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.8.0-win64_rubenvb.7z/download)

For 32-bit machine: [32-Bit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/gcc-4.8-release/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.8.0-win32_rubenvb.7z/download)

Comment: the only one i found wasn't multilib enabled

Comment: Yes If you try `gcc -v` will show multilib in there means it is `multilib` enabled

Comment: I can see --enalbe-multilib=1 but seems that doesn't work... I'm using eclipse as editor... I'll try compiling my self

Comment: using comand line it works... with eclipse it doesn't and give lot's of link error... I have to investigate better

Comment: try by passing to cross compile from 64-bit machine you need to pass `-m32` to `gcc` i.e `gcc -m32 file.c`

Comment: i never used eclipse but there has to option to configure compiler

Comment: I'm using cross gcc, and I specified my x64 compiler, I had -m32 to try x86 build but I've errors.

Comment: resolved... I downloaded NetBeans for C++ and MYSY (just for make) now all works fine

Comment: Can you please describe the exact configuration of the builds you gave link for? Host platform, target platform, exception impl, threading impl?