# Unable to complie for 32-bit EXE from 64-bit gcc in Windows 10

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I tried to compile a program to **32-bit system** from **64-bit gcc**.

I use **Windows 10**.

I confirmed **gcc version** by `gcc -v`, which outputs `Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32`.

The program is as follows,

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    printf("The Size is: %llu\n", sizeof(void*));

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to compile above code by `gcc -m32 -o main main.c`. But it returns lot of error.
I understood the error is related to **ld.exe**. But I am not sure how to proceed further.

The erros is,

```
gcc : C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program 
Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for 
-lmingw32
At line:1 char:1
+ gcc -m32 -o main .\main.c 2> error.txt
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (C:/Program File...g for -lmingw32:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program 
Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingw32.a when searching for 
-lmingw32
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program 
Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for 
-lmingw32
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find 
-lmingw32
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0\libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/libgcc_eh.a when searching for -lgcc_eh
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0\libgcc_eh.a when searching for -lgcc_eh
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/libgcc_eh.a when searching for -lgcc_eh
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find 
-lgcc_eh
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program 
Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for 
-lmoldname
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program 
Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmoldname.a when searching for 
-lmoldname
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program 
Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for 
-lmoldname
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find 
-lmoldname
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program 
Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for 
-lmingwex
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program 
Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingwex.a when searching for 
-lmingwex
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program 
Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for 
-lmingwex
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find 
-lmingwex
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a 
when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmsvcrt.a 
when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a 
when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find 
-lmsvcrt
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program 
Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libpthread.dll.a when searching for 
-lpthread
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program 
Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libpthread.a when searching for 
-lpthread
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program 
Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libpthread.a when searching for 
-lpthread
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program 
Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libpthread.dll.a when searching for 
-lpthread
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program 
Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libpthread.a when searching for 
-lpthread
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find 
-lpthread
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program 
Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libadvapi32.a when searching for 
-ladvapi32
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program 
Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libadvapi32.a when searching for 
-ladvapi32
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program 
Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libadvapi32.a when searching for 
-ladvapi32
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find 
-ladvapi32
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program 
Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libshell32.a when searching for 
-lshell32
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program 
Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libshell32.a when searching for 
-lshell32
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program 
Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libshell32.a when searching for 
-lshell32
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find 
-lshell32
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libuser32.a 
when searching for -luser32
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libuser32.a 
when searching for -luser32
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libuser32.a 
when searching for -luser32
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find 
-luser32
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program 
Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libkernel32.a when searching for 
-lkernel32
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program 
Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libkernel32.a when searching for 
-lkernel32
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program 
Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libkernel32.a when searching for 
-lkernel32
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find 
-lkernel32
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libiconv.a 
when searching for -liconv
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libiconv.a 
when searching for -liconv
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libiconv.a 
when searching for -liconv
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find 
-liconv
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program 
Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for 
-lmingw32
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program 
Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingw32.a when searching for 
-lmingw32
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program 
Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for 
-lmingw32
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find 
-lmingw32
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0\libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/libgcc_eh.a when searching for -lgcc_eh
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0\libgcc_eh.a when searching for -lgcc_eh
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/libgcc_eh.a when searching for -lgcc_eh
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find 
-lgcc_eh
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program 
Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for 
-lmoldname
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program 
Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmoldname.a when searching for 
-lmoldname
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program 
Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for 
-lmoldname
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find 
-lmoldname
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program 
Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for 
-lmingwex
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program 
Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingwex.a when searching for 
-lmingwex
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program 
Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for 
-lmingwex
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find 
-lmingwex
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a 
when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmsvcrt.a 
when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping 
incompatible C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a 
when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find 
-lmsvcrt
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Help me overcome the issue and compile a program to **32-bit system** from **64-bit gcc** in **Windows 10**.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19690504/how-do-i-compile-and-link-a-32-bit-windows-executable-using-mingw-w64 *Both DWARF and SEH variants (which come starting from GCC 4.8.0) are only single-target.*

Comment: Also related maybe duplicate, but very old https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345584/mingw64-cannot-compile-32bit-code

Comment: Try a different MinGW version. [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075) has a vesion targeting 32 bits.

Comment: I found a work-around for make 32-bit exe. Initially, I was trying CodeBlock's wingw binaries with -m32 flag, which outputs error. Now, I installed separate wingw and used for compilation of 32-bit exe. It was successful. So I decided to use both binaries. Depends on objective, i will choose either one

Comment: Please make this a proper answer. You might want to read some of the [help] to learn how this site works.

Answer (score -1):

I found a work-around for make 32-bit exe. Initially, I was trying CodeBlock's mingw binaries with -m32 flag, which outputs error. Now, I installed separate mingw (mingw installation executable) and used for compilation of 32-bit exe. It was successful. So I decided to use both binaries. Depends on objective, i will choose either one